# Unknown "BESbswy" <span>

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-maps, google-api

I've just noticed that some strange **span is being added automatically** to the end of body with left and top with -999 and visibility hidden.
I work with wordpress (if it matters).
The span looks exactly like this:

```
<span style="position: absolute; left: -999px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"> BESbswy <span>
```

**It contains "BESbswy" string.**

I have read some [article](https://tomjn.com/2012/09/13/typekit-besbswy/) on the web that says this is a runtime test in the [Typekit/Webfontloader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader/blob/master/src/core/fontwatchrunner.js#L62), which I'm not using at all.
All the pages uses Google Maps API and contain maps so i realized that this span is been added with google maps, since i cant see it in another page, that doesn't include a map.
When i remove the map from my page i cant see the span anymore.
If the Google Maps API seems to create one of these "BESbewy" span elements, 
**Can someone help me to understand what is this BESbewy thing? and how to make make it disappear?**
[image]
Tnx!

**## UPDATE ##**

I made a script that solve this issue, a **temporary solution**, until i will find out what is this span :|

```
  var clearSpan = setInterval(function () {
      var x = $("span:contains('BESbswy')");
      if(x.length != 0){
          $(x).text("");
          clearInterval(clearSpan);
      }
},100);
setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(clearSpan);},5000);
```

Comment: I'm getting this too, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Nmaster88 i made a temporary solution. i use interval to remove it from my page. hope it helps. :)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75147124/14156824

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with simple css regule:

```
span[style*='top: -999px']{display: none;}
```

Span is generated by GoogleMaps plugin.
Couldn't find other way to fix it.

Comment: it doesnt work. span is being added automatically after few seconds. I also  tried with window.onload. Nothing... :|

Comment: Only one thing i would change is maybe make the rule more specific:
body > span[style*='top: -999px']{display: none;}

Comment: The span is being added automatically after few seconds, so it doesn't work :| tnx...

Comment: Apparently it's a test string loaded by a WebFonts Loader. See here, bottom of linked section: https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader#custom